Change the resolution of a video being sent to the WebRtcEndpoint
I have crated a kurento media chain that decodes RTSP video and passes it on to a WebRtcEndpoint to send to the client. I have a capsfilter filter inline to change the video resolution.
capsFilter = new GStreamerFilter
    .Builder(sourceParticipant.getMediaPipeline(), "capsfilter caps=" + capsFilterParam)
    .withFilterType(FilterType.VIDEO)
    .build();

What I want is to be able to change the resolution while the video is being played. I have tried
capsFilter.setElementProperty("caps", capsFilterParam);

But I get the error:
org.kurento.client.internal.server.KurentoServerException: Property type not implemented: GParamBoxed

Is there a way to do this? I am using Kurento 7.0.0
